# Getting UrlError While running Python code for extracting Url from in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, url, anaconda

Below is the stack trace at the terminal end in Ubuntu
Even my anacinda is taking too much time to open (around 20 minutes)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1406, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 938, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TASK_1.py", line 23, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(line,context=gcontext)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/home/narendra/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

below is my code.

this code is extracting the Url data into the file

it will one by one pick URLs for the url.txt

then it will extract the all page data from that particular URL.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import io
import ssl
#localhost, 127.0.0.0/8, ::1, 10.0.0.0/8
# using readline() that reads file line by line. 
file1 = open("url.txt", "r") 
count = 0
gcontext = ssl.SSLContext()`
```

for i in range(18): 
       count += 1

```
   # Getting the  next line from file 
   line = file1.readline() 
   # if line is empty 
   # end of file is reached 
   if not line: 
      break
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(line,context=gcontext)
   webContent = response.read()
   with io.open("file_" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(webContent)
       f.close()
```